# none vs 0 - when are they equivalent, and when not, in CSS color functions?

Tags: css, colors, color-space, lab-color-space

I'm trying to understand `none` vs `0` in CSS color functions by creating some visual examples in CodePen.  My current understanding is that, at least in practical terms, `none` and `0` are equivalent except when interpolating between colors of different spaces.  When setting the value for a single, static color, none and zero should produce the same result on screen. See the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#missing_color_components).

But I see at least one exception to this, where zero outputs color and none outputs black.  These two values produce visibly different results on screen:

`lch(none 90 0)` vs `lch(0 90 0)`

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-grow:1;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="background-color:lch(none 90 90);"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lch(0 90 90);"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div style="background-color:lab(none 90 90);"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lab(0 90 90);"></div>
</div>
```

Same for `lab()`, which shares the lightness parameter. But it doesn't apply to the hue in `lch()`, at least not in Chrome. In Firefox setting hue to none sets the output to black, so one of them is wrong...

This example indicates that none and zero are different beyond interpolating between two separate colors. Can someone please clarify that, or point me to some docs that explain it for dummies like me?

Also, what are some specific examples where interpolating between two colors produces different results with `none` vs `0`? I am using `linear-gradient()` as my interpolater for test purposes, and I am having trouble finding cases where `none` vs `0` makes a difference in the interpolation of a linear gradient.

Edit: after posting this question I saw that the example snippet displays differently in Chrome vs Firefox - the left and right sides visually (`none` vs `0` in the CSS) are flipped between the two browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Firefox is incorrect; `lch(0% 90 90)` should produce black according to the [CSS specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#specifying-lab-lch). You can also see that Firefox and Safari are [failing the LCH test that should generate a black square](https://wpt.fyi/results/css/css-color/lch-010.html), and instead generates a [red colour](https://wpt.live/css/css-color/lch-010.html).

It's not clear to me what the browser *should* do when using `none` but `lch(none 90 90)` generating a red colour is understandable:

- `LCH [0, 90, 90]` with D50 reference white is `RGB [42, -5, -73]`
- Since it hasn't been explicitly specified that there is "0% lightness" (i.e. black), it simply clamps to `RGB [42, 0, 0]` or `#2a0000`
- Likewise, `LAB [0, 90, 90]` with D50 reference white is `RGB [97, -50, -72]` which becomes `RGB [97, 0, 0]` or `#610000`

For some reason Firefox is treating `none` as **"no lightness"** instead of **"unspecified"**, and ignoring that "0% lightness" should be treated as black.

Comment: *"It's not clear to me what the browser should do when using none"* [It should treat is as a zero value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#missing)

Comment: @gre_gor, the MDN docs agree, as they should.  So that would mean that both Chrome and Firefox are wrong relative to the snippet in my question.  All 4 rectangles should be black, right? fyi I had already submitted this bug to Firefox prior to figuring half of this out and submitting this question: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1886570

Comment: @gre_gor thanks for spotting that, sure sounds like all 4 rectangles should be black.

Comment: My Firefox bug report relates to this codepen: https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/NWmpjyz and here I would say Firefox is wrong too, because it is handling `none` differently from `0` within a single color value, no interpolation.  Am I correct there? Sorry, maybe that should be a separate question...

Answer (score 0):

I opened a discussion at github/color.js to see if anyone there could provide more definitive answers:

https://github.com/color-js/color.js/discussions/495

To summarize the response there:

a) Yes, for single color values, `none` and `0` should produce the same results on screen.

b) Firefox handles `none` incorrectly (no one on Bugzilla has responded to my bug there yet).

c) Chrome and Safari use clipping aka clamping instead of gamut mapping, and the snippet in my question should not show black at all.  Safari gets this right, but Chrome displays black for `0`, which means it doesn't match `none`, which means it's incorrect.  So no, not all the rectangles should be black, but they should all be the same on the left and right sides, i.e. the same for `none` vs `0`. I have submitted a new bug for Chrome here: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/331383943.

If you want to dig deeper regarding CSS handling of lightness, see this w3c/csswg-drafts discussion:

https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/8794

Thanks to @wacton and @gre_gor for chipping in.  I'm not marking any answer as "accepted", at least not yet.  This is messy, relatively new stuff for the browsers, messier than I had anticipated based on the documentation available.